# Conflicting libraries versions when using azure-cosmosdb-spark

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, sbt, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to write a Spark application that connects to CosmosDB using *azure-cosmosdb-spark*. However I keep getting dependencies conflicts even though I'm using the right versions of Spark and Scala.
I managed to use the connector on an Azure Databricks cluster having the same Spark version so I'm a bit lost on what is the problem here.

I already read these posts ([Developing scala spark app that connect to azure CosmosDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352809/developing-scala-spark-app-that-connect-to-azure-cosmosdb) & [Spark libraries conflect when cosmosdb Lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353714/spark-libraries-conflect-when-cosmosdb-lib)) but still couldn't solve my problem.

Here is the part of my SBT configuration trying to use the connector:

```
sparkVersion in ThisBuild := "2.2.0" // I also tried "2.2.1"
sparkComponents in ThisBuild += "mllib"
spIgnoreProvided in ThisBuild := true

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.12"
parallelExecution in ThisBuild := false
scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-implicits", "-feature")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(shaker, ...)
  .settings(Publish.notPublished: _*)

lazy val shaker = project
  .settings(name := "project-name")
  .settings(libraryDependencies += "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.9.0")
  .settings(libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.7.0")
  .settings(libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11" % "1.1.1")
  .settings(scalacOptions += "-Xmacro-settings:materialize-derivations")
```

I get the following error when running SBT:

```
[error] (shaker/*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
```

Thank for your help !

Comment: Could you post full build somewhere, including the plugins necessary for the above build.sbt? Also could you try using the latest sbt?